# Getting an error when trying to import Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm getting a Traceback (most recent call last) error when trying to use import openpyxl:

The only line of code i have is

'''

```
import openpyxl
```

'''

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rwarke/PycharmProjects/Helloworld/HelloWorld.py", line 1, in <module>
    import openpyxl
  File "C:\Users\rwarke\PycharmProjects\Helloworld\openpyxl\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
  File "C:\Users\rwarke\PycharmProjects\Helloworld\openpyxl\workbook\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .workbook import Workbook
  File "C:\Users\rwarke\PycharmProjects\Helloworld\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 7, in <module>
    from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet
  File "C:\Users\rwarke\PycharmProjects\Helloworld\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 24, in <module>
    from openpyxl.cell import Cell, MergedCell
  File "C:\Users\rwarke\PycharmProjects\Helloworld\openpyxl\cell\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cell import Cell, WriteOnlyCell, MergedCell
  File "C:\Users\rwarke\PycharmProjects\Helloworld\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 27, in <module>
    from openpyxl.styles import numbers, is_date_format
  File "C:\Users\rwarke\PycharmProjects\Helloworld\openpyxl\styles\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .alignment import Alignment
  File "C:\Users\rwarke\PycharmProjects\Helloworld\openpyxl\styles\alignment.py", line 5, in <module>
    from openpyxl.descriptors import Bool, MinMax, Min, Alias, NoneSet
  File "C:\Users\rwarke\PycharmProjects\Helloworld\openpyxl\descriptors\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "C:\Users\rwarke\PycharmProjects\Helloworld\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from openpyxl.utils.datetime import from_ISO8601
  File "C:\Users\rwarke\PycharmProjects\Helloworld\openpyxl\utils\datetime.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jdcal import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jdcal'
```

Can someone please let me know what i need to do here? Is it an error with the installation

Thanks,

Comment: have you installed openpyxl

Comment: Yes I have installed the latest version. 3.0.3

Comment: okay try the below ans and see

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments?

Comment: You haven't installed openpyxl correctly.

Answer (score 0):

it seems openpyxl depends upon jdcal so installing 'jdcal' will do the trick

```
pip install jdcal
```

Comment: That worked for the last error, Looks like a load of the modules are missing in my download of openpyxl. Will work through it. thank you for your help.

Comment: okay, you welcome, u should mark it as Answered if it answered your question

Comment: This isn't necessary if openpyxl is installed correctly.